# "WriteLine" does not work

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have a problem

I use this code to save to txt file, how to do not to overwrite the file, but would write line by line the next time a function call??

Command WriteLine does not work.
Write overwrite the file.

```
private async Task WriteToFile()
{
    string ResultString = string.Join("\n", locationData.ToArray());

    byte[] fileBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ResultString);

    StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var dataFolder = await local.CreateFolderAsync("DataFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    var file = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync("DataFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

    using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        s.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
    }
}
```

I used Windows Phone 8.1 for my app.

Comment: where are you calling `WriteLine Write and WriteLine` are not the same thing..

Comment: If you're asking how to not overwrite the file s with each function call, this is an exact duplicate of [How to append a file, asynchronously in Windows Phone 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057768/how-to-append-a-file-asynchronously-in-windows-phone-8)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, ResultString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seek to the end of the stream returned from OpenStreamForWriteAsync before doing the write.

```
s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    await writer.WriteAsync(ResultString);
    await writer.FlushAsync();
}
```